# Setting the constraint twice before calling add()

Tags: java, swing, gridlayoutmanager

I am learning GridBagLayout in swing using tutorials form Oracle.
As we all know, we can set the constraint again after being used by 1 component.Here I noticed the author is set the constraint again before call the method add().

```
public class GridBagLayoutDemo {
//Here I have no idea why these 3 lines for
    final static boolean shouldFill = true;
    final static boolean shouldWeightX = true;
    final static boolean RIGHT_TO_LEFT = false;

    public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
//1)why not just ignore the above declaration and just type 
//pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT); ?

        if (RIGHT_TO_LEFT) {
            pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        }

        JButton button;
    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
//same go to here
    if (shouldFill) {
    //natural height, maximum width
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    }
//2)the author set the constraint in above line,then author set it again in below line
    button = new JButton("Button 1");
    if (shouldWeightX) {
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    }
//here it is
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    pane.add(button, c);
```

Anyone please answer both my questions?

Comment: 1) the default layout for components is left-to-right. You only want to change the layout orientation when the variable is set. 2) that would seem to be an error. The "shouldFill" variable does nothing, since as you noted it is set anyway

Comment: 1)Thanks, I get what you mean. 2)Agree to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the second layout orientation: `c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;` is a mistake, the first one is conditional and depends from the previous seted value "shouldFill". So I do not agree that this variable does nothing.